# Compiling/installing driver for Wifi dongle missing kernel modules?

Tags: debian, wifi, compiling, drivers

### Goal

Install the `Netis wf2190` wifi dongle onto a NUC with Debian.

### Environment

- [NUC DC3217IYE](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-dc3217iye.html)
- [Netis WF2190](http://www.netis-systems.com/en/products/Dualband-Series/904.html#.VDu2I9SUf0k)
- Debian Linux `3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.3-2~bpo70+1 (2014-09-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- Installed `build-essential`

I got the driver from the website, and all I am supposed to do is run a script `install.sh` which throws me this error when trying to compile. I do have the `/lib/modules/3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64/` directory, but no `build` folder. I have tried adding this folder, but the script is apparently looking for some source files and I don't know what they are and where to get them.

Any tip?

### Error

```
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64/build M=/root/netis-wf2190/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902  modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

#### ... after creating the missing `build` folder

it is looking for rules (??)

```
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64/build M=/root/netis-wf2190/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/lib/modules/3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lib/modules/3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64/build'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

#### Here how I have installed the kernel

Added `deb http://http.debian.net/debian-backports squeeze-backports(-sloppy) main` to `source.list` and then

```
 aptitude -t wheezy-backports install linux-image-amd64
```

How do install kernel source for `3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64` kernel?

I tried this which RESOLVED!

```
 # apt-get install linux-headers-3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64
```

from `/lib/modules/3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64`

```
 ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64/ build
```

and ran `install.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***NOTE:*** I'm on Fedora 20 but the issue would be the same here, only the pathing and Linux kernel version numbers are different.

When I downloaded and attempted to run the install script, `bash ./install.sh` I noticed this error message as well.

> make: *** /lib/modules/3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.

The script isn't equipped to make this directory and is expecting that it's already there for it to use:

```
/lib/modules/3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64/build
```

Checking shows that it's not there:

```
$ cd /lib/modules/3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64/build
bash: cd: /lib/modules/3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64/build: No such file or directory
```

This directory can be a bit confusing, but if you change directories 1 level up, the situation is a bit clearer:

```
$ cd /lib/modules/3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64/
$ ls -l | grep build
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root     39 Sep 29 14:25 build -> /usr/src/kernels/3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64
```

So `build` is a link to another directory. In this case it's a link where the Kernel's development tree would be installed if you had them installed. So to resolve this you simply need to install a package for your distro that includes them.

On Fedora these packages go by the name `kernel-devel-<kernel version #>`, so I suspect that if you simply installed those, you'd be all set.

Comment: That seems pretty logical. I have tried installing a few additional packages to no avail. As you say the naming convention may be different for Debian.

Comment: Updated my question with Resolution! I needed to run `apt-get install linux-headers-3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64` and create symbolic link! Thanks slm